# C++ Windows function "LockResource()" returns half the data in the resource

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, embedded-resource

I am trying to read an embedded resource from a dll, it contains an encrypted file. Reading it from `LockResource()` , only returns half the data.

The funny thing is that I checked `SizeOfResource()` and the size of the resource is what it is supposed to be.

**So I tried to access the file without it being an embedded resource :**

```
 std::ifstream enc("Logs.enc" , std::ios::binary);              // Accessing encrypted file
    std::string ciphertext = std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(enc)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    int size = ciphertext.size();   //  Returns the correct size
```

This worked , I tried to find something they have in common and I tried to remove the `std::ios::binary` and it had similar behavior to when accessing the file as a resource.

**Here is my attempt to Access it as a resource :**

```
 HGLOBAL SHEET_DATA;      // Imagine this has the encrypted file
        if (SHEET_DATA) {
            char* datac = nullptr;
            datac = (char*)LockResource(SHEET_DATA);
             std::string data = datac;
            long size_sheet = SizeofResource(dll, SHEET);  // 

            int real_size = data.size();    // Returns the wrong size
        }
```

I tried to search if there was anything such as a `LockResource()` function that accessess the data in binary mode , but I couldn't find any results.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen` is assuming the parameter is a zero terminated string. It counts the chars until it gets to the zero termination.

In your case it seems like the resource is binary. In this case it may contain bytes with the value 0, which `strlen` treats as the end of the string.

Therefore what `strlen` returns is irrelevant. You can use `size_sheet` returned from `SizeofResource` to know the size of the data pointed by `datac`.

**Update:**
The updated question does not contain a usage of `strlen` anymore. But the line:

```
std::string data = datac;
```

Create a similar problem. Initializing an `std::string` from a `char*` assumes the `char*` is pointing to a zero terminated string. So if the buffer contains zeroes the resulting string will contain only the characters till the first zero.
You can initialize the `std::string` the following way to avoid the assumption of the zero termination:

```
std::string data(datac, size_sheet);
```

Giving the length of the buffer to the ctor of `std::string` will force initializing with the complete buffer (ignoring the zeroes).

**Update2:** As @IInspectable commented below, if the data is not really a string, better hold it in a more suitable container - e.g. `std::vector<char>`. It also has a constructor accepting a `char*` and the buffer's length.

Comment: Hi Thanks for Posting an answer , pls see my updated question , because I wrote the question wrong , I convert the char* I recieve from "LockResource()" into a std::string and then call ".size()" from that string , and ".size()" returns the right size when accessing it from a file , but it returns the wrong size when accessing it from a resource .

Comment: This line: `std::string data = datac` (like `strlen`) also assumes that the string pointer by `datac` is zero terminated (similarly to the issue with `strlen`). So it makes sense that `data.size()` will return the size until the first '\0'. Can it be that your resource buffer is binary and contains zeros ?

Comment: Accessing it as a file returns the right size though

Comment: But there you initialize the `std::string` from `std::istreambuf_iterator`.

Comment: Updated my answer about the current problem in the code (after removing `strlen`).

Comment: Okay , i'm gonna check this out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244185/discussion-between-iber999-and-wohlstad).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
 std::string data = datac;
```

This constructs a `std::string` from a null-terminated string. But `datac` is not a null-terminated string, as you said it's binary data. Instead, use the `string (const char* s, size_t n);` ctor overload:

```
 std::string data(datac, size_sheet);
```